# Strange interline spacing with arraystretch in a NiceTabular

Tags: spacing, nicematrix

Good evening to all, and all the best for this new year.

I am trying to get a NiceTabular (of the NiceMatrix package) with some text in it, and as I would like it to be more airy than normal, I use `\def\arraystretch{2}`. However, the result within my table is very strange, with interline being uneven, and actually depending on the line: the interline is big between the first and the second line, then normal, then even bigger between the penultimate and the last line.

[image]

Could you please help me to understand what is happening there, and how to ensure that the lines in one cell are equally spaced between each other? Would you use any other way to have an "airy" table?

I am also trying to get rid of any horizontal space within the table left and right of each row, so that the borders are aligned with the text on the left and the numbers on the right - if you have any idea on how to do, I would be very grateful.

Thank you very much all!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{2}

\noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{b{5.5cm}b{1.5cm}}[code-before =
{\tikz \draw [black] (row-3-|col-1) -- (row-3-|col-3) ;
\tikz \draw [black] (row-4-|col-1) -- (row-4-|col-3) ;
\tikz \draw [black] (row-5-|col-1) -- (row-5-|col-3) ;
\tikz \draw [black] (row-6-|col-1) -- (row-6-|col-3) ;
\tikz \draw [black] (row-7-|col-1) -- (row-7-|col-3) ;
\tikz \draw [black] (row-8-|col-1) -- (row-8-|col-3) ;
}]
Only one row looks fine & \Block[r]{1-1}{1} \\
Two rows have a very big space between them & \Block[r]{1-1}{2} \\
Three rows show one small space first, and then a bigger one, but not too bad & \Block[r]{1-1}{3} \\
Four rows look much weirder, with big space between the first two rows, small space then, and big space again& \Block[r]{1-1}{4} \\
Five rows has only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. & \Block[r]{1-1}{5} \\
Six rows is even weirder with only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. & \Block[r]{1-1}{5} \\
\end{NiceTabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Good evening also for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see/understand your problem, use of the `NiceTabular` package it is not the best tool for achieving of the desired goal. For example, with `tabularray` you can get it much easier and simpler:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{hline{2-Z},
                 colspec = {Q[j,b, wd=5.5cm] Q[r,b, wd=1.5cm]},
                 rowsep  = 2ex,
                 }
Only one row looks fine &   1   \\
Two rows have a very big space between them 
                        &   2   \\
Three rows show one small space first, and then a bigger one, but not too bad 
                        &   3   \\
Four rows look much weirder, with big space between the first two rows, small space then, and big space again
                        &   4   \\
Five rows has only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. 
                        &   5   \\
Six rows is even weirder with only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. 
                        &   6   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use this code for `code-before`  or `\CodeAfter`.

[image: c]

(There is no row 8)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % expand the cells
    
    \noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{b{5.5cm}b{1.5cm}}[
        code-before =
        \tikz \draw  (2-|1) -- (2-|3); 
        \tikz \draw  (3-|1) -- (3-|3);
        \tikz \draw  (4-|1) -- (4-|3); 
        \tikz \draw  (5-|1) -- (5-|3);
        \tikz \draw  (6-|1) -- (6-|3);  
        \tikz \draw  (7-|1) -- (7-|3);  
        ]
        Only one row looks fine & \Block[r]{1-1}{1} \\
        Two rows have a very big space between them & \Block[r]{1-1}{2} \\
        Three rows show one small space first, and then a bigger one, but not too bad & \Block[r]{1-1}{3} \\
        Four rows look much weirder, with big space between the first two rows, small space then, and big space again& \Block[r]{1-1}{4} \\
        Five rows has only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. & \Block[r]{1-1}{5} \\
        Six rows is even weirder with only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. & \Block[r]{1-1}{6} \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \newpage
    
    \noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{b{5.5cm}b{1.5cm}}
        Only one row looks fine & \Block[r]{1-1}{1} \\
        Two rows have a very big space between them & \Block[r]{1-1}{2} \\
        Three rows show one small space first, and then a bigger one, but not too bad & \Block[r]{1-1}{3} \\
        Four rows look much weirder, with big space between the first two rows, small space then, and big space again& \Block[r]{1-1}{4} \\
        Five rows has only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. & \Block[r]{1-1}{5} \\
        Six rows is even weirder with only one big space between first and second row, then ok, then an even bigger one between the penultimate and the ultimate. & \Block[r]{1-1}{6} \\
        \CodeAfter      
        \tikz \draw  (2-|1) -- (2-|3); 
        \tikz \draw  (3-|1) -- (3-|3); 
        \tikz \draw  (4-|1) -- (4-|3); 
        \tikz \draw  (5-|1) -- (5-|3);
        \tikz \draw  (6-|1) -- (6-|3);  
        \tikz \draw  (7-|1) -- (7-|3);      
    \end{NiceTabular}   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Simon,

Thank you so much for your reply. Very strangely, when I copy-paste your code to my tex editor (I have a MacTeX distribution) with nothing else of course, I get exactly the same result as I had in the first place, with weird spacing among the . I have no idea what may happen there...